# Multiprocessing map on object parameters

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've got an object which contains a list of objects. I'd like to do something like:

```
def compute_weight(particle, data):
    particle.weight = run_computation(data)

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.particles = [obj1, obj2, etc]

    def run(self, data):
        [compute_weight(particle, data) for p in self.particles]
```

These can run independently, but I need self.particles to contain each updated particle. Currently, I have a trick to shove two arguments into the pool.map function

```
            # equivalent function as above
            pool.map(compute_weight_star, itertools.izip(self.particles,
                                                         itertools.repeat(data)))
```

but each particle.weight don't seem to be updating. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the particle objects get updated in the worker processes, but they are communicated back to the master process. Consider the following simplified example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

particles = [[0], [0], [0]]

def compute_weight(particle):
    particle[0] = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pool().map(compute_weight, particles)
    print(particles)
```

You'll find that this leaves the particle weights (the lists' first elements) at 0, while they should be 1.

The solution is to compute the particle weights in the worker processes, but do the storage part in the master process:

```
def compute_weight(particle):
    return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Pool().map(compute_weight, particles)
    for i, p in enumerate(particles):
        p[0] = w[i]     # set weight
    print(particles)
```